# Updating attribute table with area

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I want to update a certain field with the current area.
What I have tried:

```
updated_area = iface.addVectorLayer(xx.shp, "", "ogr")

selected_feature = updated_area.selectedFeatures()
updated_area.startEditing()

for feature in selected_feature:
    feature["area"] = "$area"
    updated_area.updateFeature(feature)
updated_area.commitChanges()
```

I'm not getting any errors, but nor is it updating any fields.

Comment: Do you need the python approach ? If not, you can create a virtual field from the field calculator, defined as $area.  Otherwise if you want pyqgis to do the evaluation, your feature["area"] field should be something like 'feature.geometry().area()"

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I do. It's a part of a bigger script.

Comment: does your shapefile have the area attribute already ? or does it need to be created by the script ?

Comment: There is a field called area already, but because of some clipping in the script, it needs an update. 
I wouldn't mind deleting it and adding a new instead, any work-around would do.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to update the ares, but for what ever reason the numbers are whacked. Like in an unidentified unit.

```
updated_area = iface.addVectorLayer(xx.shp, "", "ogr")
    
area_idx = updated_area.fields().lookupField('area')

for f in updated_area.getFeatures():
    area = f.geometry().area()*626336.7007
    updated_area.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({f.id(): {area_idx: area}})
```

By multiplying it with 626336.7007 I'm getting the correct numbers, however, but I would like to skip this work around.

Comment: You haven't told us the CRS of your layer and what is the unit you are expecting.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. =/

Comment: Go in your vector layer properties, the first tab, you have a section "Coordinate Reference System (CRS)". Please edit your question with these info.

Comment: If you don't know how to retrieve the CRS of the current layer using QGIS desktop, it seems you have a few more things to know in GIS and QGIS in general before diving into PyQGIS

Comment: I meant, I don't know how to do that in code. Using the GUI is not an option.

Comment: To be able to answer you to original question, we need to know your CRS ... If you really want to do it with pyqgis : `iface.activeLayer().crs()`  https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#ab7c94eb6dc64f7f6c08298f88a3003e4

Comment: Outputs "EPSG:4326", as expected. But what I don't get is when I manually update the field with $area in the attribute table, the values are stated in square metres. I would assume that it would be the same by running the above snippet, but it isn't.

Comment: `$area` you are using the QGIS expression engine, when using `QgsGeometry.area()`, you are using the geometry from the layer in the current CRS layer.